# How can i solve this question with Geometric distribution or random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I tried have tried using a 'Geometric distribution', but it hasn't worked.

John and Ron play basketball 10 times.
The probability that John wins in single round = $0.4$.
The probability that Ron wins in single round = $0.3$.
The probability that there is equality between them in a single round = $0.3$.
The "Winner" is defined to be the first to win a single round.
The rotations are different and independent.

*What is the probability that John is the Winner?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they only play $10$ times, the probability that John wins is equal to the sum of probabilities that John wins in the $i$-th round:

$$P=\sum_{i=1}^{10}\left ( 0.3^{i-1}\times 0.4\right )=0.4\times\frac{1-0.3^{10}}{0.7}$$

where the probability that John wins in the $i$-th round is $0.3^{i-1}\times 0.4$ because the first $i-1$ rounds were all draws.

Comment: You used "geometric distribution"?

Comment: I also thought to do that, but if i uses "gemoetric distribution", it's not need to be from this pattern $p^{i-1}*(1-p)$?

Comment: It's not a geometric distribution because these are not Bernoulli trials, since in each round the probability that John wins and loses is not $p$ and $1-p$.  (there's a third state in the form of draws)

Comment: And I guess if they played until winner, you would replace $10$ with $\infty$, right?

Comment: Yes, which would yield $P= \frac{4}{7}$ as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Given that there are exactly $10$ rounds, the probability of having no winner by the end of the $10$ rounds is $0.3^{10}$. Then we know that the probability of having a winner is $1-0.3^{10}$.

Such probability should be apportioned between John and Ron in the ratio $0.4/0.3$. So the probability that John wins is 
$$\frac{4}{7} (1-0.3^{10})$$

Answer (score 0):

Let J be the probability that John wins a round. (0.3)
Let T be the probability that there is no winner for the round. (0.3)
Let WJn be the probability that John wins in round n **or later**.

WJ1 = J + T*WJ2

WJ2 = J + T*WJ3

:

WJ10 = J (since there are no later rounds)

Substituting and expanding

WJ1 = J + JT + JT^2 + ... + JT^9

WJ1 = J * (sum i=0 to 9)T^i

WJ1 = 0.3 * 1.43 = 0.43